# find last comma with string SQLITE

Tags: sqlite, substr

Is there a way to find last comma with a string and replace it?

There are yellow, blue, green, orange fruits.

to

There are yellow, blue, green and orange fruits.

It would be very simple to find first comma:

> `substr(text, instr(text, '.'), 1) from table..`

But I am looking for a dynamic solution to do it from behind.

Answer (score 1):

If you reverse the string, then using 'instr' would work. You can write a custom function to reverse the string.